# Sequelize Op.like and Op.or failing

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, sequelize.js

i have this issue with Sequelize:
I'm trying to have a 3 parameter research and if one of those parameter is empty it should not consider that parameter.

```
const users = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    category: { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.category}%` },
    location: { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.location}%` },
    [Op.or]: [
      { job: { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.job}%` } },
      { bio: { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.job}%` } },
      { skills: { [Op.like]: `%${req.query.job}%` } },
    ],
  },
  attributes: { exclude: ['password', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'] },
})
```

I've found out that the `[Op.like]` is not working anywhere.
It only works if a parameter is empty (blocks that parameter from filtering the users and that's something i like).

When i do a research with the example payload `{category:'Information Technology', job:'frontend web dev', location:'Sydn'}` this is logged in the process log:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `image`, `location`, `phone`,
`website`, `availability`, `category`, `job`, `skills`, `bio` FROM `Users` AS `User`
WHERE (`User`.`job` LIKE '%frontend web dev%' OR `User`.`bio` LIKE '%frontend web dev%' OR
`User`.`skills` LIKE '%frontend web dev%') AND `User`.`category` LIKE '%Information Technology%'
AND `User`.`location` LIKE '%Sydn%';
```

but no user is found. (yes, in the database  I have users with similar parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should looks more like this:

```
category: { [Op.like]: '%`${req.query.category}%`' },
```

What I did here is add single quote mark `'`. Reference to the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)

Comment: Hi Andrew. Unfortunately it doesn't work. 
it now logs ```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `image`, `location`, `phone`, `website`, `availability`, `category`, `job`, `skills`, `bio` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE (`User`.`job` LIKE '%`${req.query.job}`%' OR `User`.`bio` LIKE '%`${req.query.job}`%' OR `User`.`skills` LIKE '%`${req.query.job}`%') AND `User`.`category` LIKE '%`${req.query.category}`%' AND `User`.`location` LIKE '%`${req.query.location}`%';
[]
```
so it's searching for similarities to  the actual '%`${req.query.category}%`' string

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your code and your logged SQL are same. I don't see any errors. Maybe you should try to copy that SQL and paste it in MySQL Workbench (if you're using MySQL) then try to run it.

Comment: Hi, i did it and it looks like the `LIKE` is not working anywere. if I look exactly for something or a field or more fields of my query are empty it works how it should. The problem is that it's like if it's not reading the `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you split out the req.query first.
Then you can choose between using Op.or and Op.and, that way, you can use either of them.

I'm not sure about using both.

Also observe how I used the `%`.

```
//typescript
export const searchUsers = async (queryRecord: Record<string, any>, or: boolean) => {
const {name, bio, category} = queryRecord;
const user = await User.findOne({
    where: {
      [or ? Op.or : Op.and]: [{ name: { [Op.like]: "%" + name + "%" } }],
    },
  });    
 };
```